# TypeError and value error

Tags: python

I have python code where I can push my data to a database.

```
   def push(self, data,lname,mname):
    self.param = data
    self.lname = lname
    self.mname = mname
    # Open database connection
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host = self.dbhost1,port = self.dbport,user = self.dbuser,passwd = self.dbpass , db = self.dbname)

    # prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
    cur = db.cursor()

    # Create table as per requirement
    cur.executemany("""
    INSERT INTO 
        """+ self.lname +"""

    VALUES
        ("""+ self.mname +""", %s, %s, %s)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        x = VALUES(x),
        y = VALUES(y),
        z = VALUES(z);
    """, self.param)
    db.commit()
    # disconnect from server
    db.close()
```

I get this error when I try to push `natom=83`

```
  d.push(data.natom,"natom","2")
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cclib\bridge\PythonSQL.py", line 46,   in push
""", self.param)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 246, in executemany
    self.errorhandler(self, TypeError, msg)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
raise errorclass, errorvalue
 TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

This error below i get then i try to push atomcoords =

```
   [[[1 2 3]
   [1 4 3] 
   [5 6 7]]]
```

I get the array above from the CCLib library of quantum chemistry calculations, I am not creating it. But still why can't I push it?

```
  d.push(data.atomcoords,"xyz","2")
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cclib\bridge\PythonSQL.py", line 46, in push
""", self.param)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 227, in executemany
if not args: return
 ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

So my code works if I try to push an array like this one.

```
[[0,2,3],[4,6,3],[5,6,9]]
```

Maybe someone knows the way, solution or knows some info and could share it why it is working only in one way? I searched a lot of solutions about those 2 errors but nothing comes to my head.

Comment: nop that not exact read the entire question

Comment: The shape of your data which is handled correctly is 3x3. The data producing an error have the shape 1x3x3. If those are numpy arrays try atomcoords = np.queeze(atomcoords)

Comment: one question per question

Comment: first of all it cant be duplicate, because it hasvalue error and type error. secondly u can think that it would be possibly duplicate of both those error. But then u think more carefully it makes no sense, so i think my sql functions is defined in a bad way or something bad with my entire code.

Comment: what do you get for print(type(data.atomcoords)) ?

Comment: I get   numpy.ndarray

Comment: @JarrodRoberson this is not a dup of "int is not iterable" because that is about a mistake that `(25)` is not a one element tuples and the answer has nothing to do with pushing integer values to an sql database.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson this is not a dup of "use a.any() or a.all()" because sql uses the boolean-ness of the expected list input, actually using `a.any()` or `a.all()` will not at all help the OP of this question and the answer again has nothing to do with SQL not supporting numpy arrays.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on your comment and http://cclib.github.io/contents.html, it seems that `atomcoords` is a numpy `array` but `executemany` expects a `list` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html). Try the following code:

```
  d.push(data.atomcoords.tolist()[0], "xyz", "2")
```

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html

Comment: I get TypeError: not all arguments cnverted during string formatting. Can it occur if there is float number or negative ones like: -0.1689 or etc ?

Comment: Try something like x = data.atomcoords.tolist() to see if the conversion works

Comment: conversion works fine, i dont get it conversion works so why push is not working. It should work. Maybe my sql function is bad ? :(

Comment: Can you add the output of tolist()?

Comment: [[[-3.120774, 1.483773, -0.252458], [-3.809956, 1.642663, 1.119125], [-4.997237, 2.604702, 1.082217]]]

Comment: its just to long so i shortened it

Comment: It seems like another there is another level inside the array. Try push... tolist()[0]

Comment: oh ty man :) i dont want to be greedy but maybe u know the way of pushing int value ? :)

Comment: I probably know but this site is not a code writing service ;) Good luck!

Comment: np, i just created def push2 method for only integers and it working just fine :)